# Node js keep making new windows of chrome even when not asked to using Cucumber framework

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am pretty new at this but my project look like this
I created with maven

```
Project directory
-Features
-a.feature
-b.feature
-c.feature
--Step_definitions
--a js
--b js
--c js
--driver js
```

In driver JS

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
//setting chrome options to start the browser fully maximized
var chromeOptions = {
    'args': ['--disable-notifications']
};
chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', chromeOptions);
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities).build();
module.exports = driver;
```

Only a and b js file call for the element driver, but some reason when running c, it keeps making new windows of chrome.
How to avoid this?